# Hashing a string to an integer in c++

Tags: c++, string, hash, type-conversion

I am trying to figure out the conversion process for strings to ints. We are doing a program with hashing, in which the key value to be hashed is the name of a state. From my research, it seems like atoi() will not work.

Do I need to break each letter of the word down and individually convert? Do I use ASCII? Am I completely going in the wrong direction?

I am very lost, so ANY information would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: You could implement something similar to java.lang.String's [hashcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()#The_java.lang.String_hash_function) function.

Comment: `std::hash(your_std_string)`?  :P  ♥ C++11

Answer (score 21, accepted):

C++11 introduces an implementation defined hashing function called `std::hash` in header `<functional>` which has speciality for the string classes `std::string`, `std::wstring`, etc.

It's as simple as doing this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional> //for std::hash
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str = "Hello World";
    std::hash<std::string> hasher;
    auto hashed = hasher(str); //returns std::size_t
    std::cout << hashed << '\n'; //outputs 2146989006636459346 on my machine
}
```

Specializing `std::hash` for your user defined types isn't very complex either. Do note however that there is no `std::hash` specialization for `const char*` or any of the C-strings.

Answer (score 7):

You need a *hash function* to turn your string into a more or less arbitrary integer. There are many to choose from, and yes they typically use the ASCII values of the string. Here's one called djb2

```
unsigned long hash(const std::string& str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
        hash = 33 * hash + (unsigned char)str[i];
    return hash;
}
```

Please don't take this as a recommendation that this is a *good* hash function, that's a whole different topic.

Comment: Would I be able to do this if the string I am trying to convert is a state name, say "Alaska" or "Illinois" ?

Comment: @user2109706 Yes, this function will convert *any* string into a hash code. The important point is that "Alaska" and "Illinois" will be converted into different hash codes (I hope).

Answer (score 7):

From  [here](https://gist.github.com/underscorediscovery/81308642d0325fd386237cfa3b44785c), there are two function to convert string to `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`, convert to `uint32_t`:

```
inline uint32_t hash_str_uint32(const std::string& str) {

    uint32_t hash = 0x811c9dc5;
    uint32_t prime = 0x1000193;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        uint8_t value = str[i];
        hash = hash ^ value;
        hash *= prime;
    }

    return hash;

}
```

Test:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) may suit your need.

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "123456";
    try
    {
       int i = boost::lexical_cast<int>(str);
       // i should be 123456 here
    }
    catch(const boost::bad_lexical_cast&)
    {
        //bad format
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about a string of digits to an integer.

Comment: Yes, I need to convert a word, like "Alaska" or "Illinois" to an int, so then I can hash it.

Comment: @user2109706: The very process of turning a (non-numeric) string into an int is hashing it.

Answer (score 0):

If the string will stay in the memory, some libraries just return the address of the string as the hash.